# How use chinese phone on Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, smartphone

I have a huge problem and I do not know how solve It. I have a chinese Smartphone, a Bluebo L100 FW with Android 4.1 ROM for Samsung S3. I'm developing Android apps with Eclipse Juno and I want to test them on my new phone. I did all the steps [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) and also I tried [this](http://blog.neodoo.es/maznar/android-2/list-of-devices-attached-no-permissions-con-adb/), but nothing of this works. I'm sure the problem is the vendor Id I have to use in the 51-adroid rules. I tried the samsung Id and the huawei also. Not working, still having the List of devices attached. 
No permissions when I use the ./adb devices. I'm using Linux btw.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to use `./adb kill-server` and `./adb start-server` as root. This fixes it for me for all devices...

Comment: Please note it is "sure" not "shure".

Comment: Ok, I was the sudo thing, I wasn't executing ./adb beeing admin. Thank's mate.

Comment: Sorry for the misspelling on shure, English is not my natural language